# Jairus Daughter

Tags: matthew, contradiction, mark, chronology

In Matthew we read:

> 15 Jesus answered, “How can the guests of the bridegroom mourn while he is with them? The time will come when the bridegroom will be taken from them; then they will fast. 16 “No one sews a patch of unshrunk cloth on an old garment, for the patch will pull away from the garment, making the tear worse. 17 Neither do people pour new wine into old wineskins. If they do, the skins will burst; the wine will run out and the wineskins will be ruined. No, they pour new wine into new wineskins, and both are preserved." 18 **While he was saying this, a synagogue leader came and knelt before him and said, “My daughter has just died. But come and put your hand on her, and she will live.” 19 Jesus got up and went with him, and so did his disciples.**

But in Mark we get something like:

> 21 **When Jesus had again crossed over by boat to the other side of the lake, a large crowd gathered around him while he was by the lake. 22 Then one of the synagogue leaders, named Jairus, came, and when he saw Jesus, he fell at his feet.** 23 He pleaded earnestly with him, “My little daughter is dying. Please come and put your hands on her so that she will be healed and live.” 24 So Jesus went with him.

How do we reconcile the chronological inconsistency considering that Matthew shares commonalities with Mark like the storm and demoniac, and the paralytic, yet places all of the events before Jairus' daughter gets raised?

Comment: *How do we reconcile the chronological inconsistency ?* - We don't.

Comment: You first need to prove - and that should be part of your question - that these are the same incident. Thousands of people flocked to Jesus, the incidents piled one on top of the other as multitudes followed him. Documented reports pick out features of the events relevant to the spiritual aspect that the individual writer portrays of Jesus Christ. This may, or may not, be the same incident.

Comment: Matthew and Mark received testimony from different sources. After all, many of the large crowd would have witnessed the event. There is nothing of substance in this question.

Comment: @NigelJ It's a given, considering we have Jesus gealing the woman with the issue of blood. and the laughter that occurs when the dead girl is sleeping.

Comment: You will find, after properly tabulating the two accounts, taking into regard _all_ of the evidence, and with due consideration to both of the contexts that there is no discrepancy. I guarantee it. Rarely - very, very rarely - we have also to take into account matters of Textual Criticism as well and we need to critically examine the manuscripts. Very few are qualified to take matters to such a level.

Comment: (+1) James - I think this is a good question that (based on your comments) you appear to have researched to a better depth than the Question itself explains. I'd suggest doing as @NigelJ asked in his first comment and more fully justifying why you see an inconsistency here that you need help resolving. It's currently at risk of closure due to 'lack of clarity', but I don't think it would take much from you to remedy that.